# How come there are demons in their true forms outside the Fade?

Tags: dragon-age

In Dragon Age, a big part of the lore is that a demon cannot exist in its true form outside the Fade. It must either possess a mage (becoming an Abomination), a corpse (undead), a tree (Sylvan), or create a makeshift body (shade).

Except throughout the games you fight tons of demons in their true forms in the real world. By this I mean the demon's form when you encounter it in the real world is the same when you encounter it in the Fade. There's only one time this is acknowledged: in Awakening, the Baroness is said to be a pride demon of such immense power that it could manifest in the real world. But all other times you encounter demons, the fact that they are in their true forms is just ignored.

Why is that? Is it just gameplay and story segregation? I understand that having players fight true demons instead of just shades or abominations leads to more diversified gameplay, but it seems like a huge lore violation.

Comment: [tears in the veil](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Codex_entry:_Tears_in_the_Veil) : "Demons seize every opportunity, every tear in the Veil, to enter our world. Once the Veil is torn, it is extremely difficult to mend, some say impossible."

Comment: My thought would simply be that art simply wasn't finished for more posessed forms, or they wanted you to simply look and say "ok, that's a wrath".  Given all the ick in the mage tower that came from nowhere, it honestly never occurred to me that demons couldn't eventually warp things to how they wanted to appear.  But that's just guessing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking the wrong question. What you should be asking is why demons look the way they do in the Fade, rather than in our world.

This is one of the conversation excerpts between Cole and Dorian:

> Dorian: You're not possessing a human body, Cole? You...actually look like that?
>
> Cole: Yes
>
> Dorian: But a spirit's true form is always monstrous, or at least unnatural.
>
> Cole: The world doesn't make sense to them. It's too real. That's why they look wrong.

This implies that the way they look in our world is not the way they *should* look in the Fade.

From the DA wikia on demons:

> ...Usually spirits or demons can only cross over the Fade by attaching themselves to something in the mortal world. Demons in particular, cannot make sense of the physical world. They are unable to tell the living from the dead or the very static nature of the physical universe. As such, it becomes very confusing for such creatures who are normally accustomed to a physicality defined entirely by emotion and memory. Thus, demons unable to reconcile with their new reality would look monstrous and wrong in the physical world.

So, the way that demons look in our world is the twisted form, and I don't believe there is an explanation for why they look the way they do in the Fade, since that should be a spirit form, not the twisted form.

Comment: Hmmmm can it be not that the fade doesnt make sense to us and thus we see the demons AND the fade distorted? (same distortion they have when they try to make sense of the real wold?)

Comment: @Thomas - That is certainly a possible interpretation, but I don't recall anything in the dialogue suggesting it. If I get some time I'll go through the hero/dorian dialogues and see if there is anything in there.

Comment: @Thomas - Although that is belied somewhat by the fact that shades appear the same in both places and that is their natural form, according to the wikia.